# Problem with Excel Update for SQL when there are many columns

Tags: excel, vba, sql-update

I'm trying to insert data via SQL but I can't.
When trying once, MS Excel does not accept it and when I insert the data and try to run the update it does not accept it in the BD.Execute SQL line

In the following code:

```
For Linhas = 2 To UltLinhaBD 

Set Planilha = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Apontamento") 
Set LinhaDados = Planilha.Rows(Linhas) 

Select SQL = "INSERT INTO [APONTAMENTO$] (ID, COD_LINHA, DATA, LOTE, COD_PRODUTO, COD_EVENTO, COD_SUBEVENTO, INICIO, TERMINO, QTDE_PROD, PERDAS, OBSERVACAO) VALUES (" & LinhaDados.Cells(1).Value & ", '" & LinhaDados.Cells(2).Value & "', '" & LinhaDados.Cells(3).Value & "', '" & LinhaDados.Cells(4).Value & "', '" & LinhaDados.Cells(5).Value & "', '" & LinhaDados.Cells(6).Value & "', '" & LinhaDados.Cells(7).Value & "', '" & Format(LinhaDados.Cells(8).Value, "h:mm") & "', '" & Format(LinhaDados.Cells(9).Value, "h:mm") & "', " & LinhaDados.Cells(10).Value & ", " & LinhaDados.Cells(11).Value & ", '" & LinhaDados.Cells(12).Value & "')" 

BD.Open cs 

Consulta.Open SQL, BD 

'Fiz o update a partir da coluna 13 

SQL = "UPDATE [APONTAMENTO$] SET VELOCIDADE = '" & LinhaDados.Cells(13).Value & "', ID_OP = " & _ LinhaDados.Cells(14).Value & ", ID_USER = " & LinhaDados.Cells(15).Value & ", HORARIO_REG = '" & _ LinhaDados.Cells(16).Value & "', COD_TURNO = '" & LinhaDados.Cells(17).Value & "' WHERE ID = " & LinhaDados.Cells(1).Value 

BD.Execute SQL 

BD.Close 

Next
```

I hope that when running it executes all 17 columns at once, if it doesn't work with the update function it can solve the problem.

Comment: It would help us if you provide some test data so we can try this. Also, what is the exact error message displayed when Excel/VBA/SQL "does not work"

Comment: I tried to do this first but I didn't get, so tried running the updated function code and it works, and after this the issue when I use in differents folders for update function.